# How can I merge finished work patch instead of its whole history into test branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

A developer starts work on a feature lets call it *"Fix a hardcoded link"*, once it's done, it's passed to another developer for peer review. Peer reviewer is ok with code changes and **merge feature branch into test branch**. *"Fix a hardcoded link"* is now on test server waiting for Technical test.

`test` is where feature branches are merged once it's been peer reviewed by another developer, `staging` is the branch where feature branches are merged once it's gone through Peer review, TT and UAT.

Next developer starts working on the next card and creates a branch like this:

```
git checkout test
git checkout -b story/bar
```

Developer finishes work and passes it to peer review. Peer reviewer is happy with the code an passes into TT and UAT, all are happy and onto P.O it goes. P.O is happy then he **merge feature branch into staging**

```
git checkout staging
git merge origin/story/bar
```

By doing that I have discovered that we are applying not only the patch attached to the fix for the particular card but also the whole history that comes with the branch. The result is the commit *"Fix a hardcoded link"* is staging but it hasn't gone through the process.

- Is there anything wrong with our approach and any suggestions to imrpove it?
- Should we create our feature branches out of staging?

Comment: Yes, if you want to review fixes separately from others, you should create (and merge back) branches that include only them (and not unrelated stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to take into account the publication workflow (push/pull), and not just the merge workflow (`feature` to `test` to `staging` to...): this publication workflow [is orthogonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917) to a [merge workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216212/how-do-you-maintain-development-code-and-production-code#216228).

Any new `feature` branch must be developed on top of the LATEST official version you want to use that `feature` with.

If it is `staging`, that means:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b newFeature origin/staging
# hack...

# make sure newFeature still works on top of staging as right now
# since staging might have received other feature 
# during the development of newFeature

git fetch
git rebase origin/staging
# local and/or unit tests...
# push for review
git push -u origin newFeature
```

When you are merging a `feature` to `test` or `staging`, you should rebase `newFeature` on top of `test`, then on top of `staging`, and merge `newFeature` only then (fast forward merge).
Any conflict during the rebase means the feature is rejected (the developer must fetch, then rebase that `newFeature` branch locally on top of what is causing trouble, in order to see why there is a conflict).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, After reading the links you've posted I am starting to see a need for a "release candidate branch" rather than staging, then we can create feature branches from "release candidate branch" instead of test

Comment: @Filype true, some kind of "official" branch, which all developers can use as a reference. But the rebase parts are important too.