# Git workflow for a complex project

Tags: git, github, gitlab, workflow

My client is a very big telco provider.

I am moving them git. I have to come up with a workflow as well.

There are developers for Application management and application development.

Application management is day to day bug, defects etc. They can go live every day for fixing these defects. But these can be database scripts as well.

In application development there are projects which can take from 1 month to 3 months.

There are 5 environments as follow:
DEV - SIT - UAT - PREPROD - PROD

For application management and appliction development these environments are different till pre-prod and prod.

Source code in Application management always goes to prod. Application development projects are merged onto it.

I am familiar with gitflow, github flow and gitlab flow.

What would be a good workflow for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Gitflow, github flow and gitlab flow are (mostly) merge workflows (between branches)

But don't forget, with Git you have a publication workflow (push/pull between repositories), which is [orthogonal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216228/6309) to a [merge workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563917/6309).

So regarding your continuous integration steps  DEV - SIT - UAT - PREPROD - PROD, you can setup dedicated Git repositories which would represent said steps.
See as an example "[I have a confession to make… I commit to master.](https://hackernoon.com/i-have-a-confession-to-make-i-commit-to-master-6a804f334beb)" from 
[Patrick Lee Scott](https://twitter.com/pat_scott).