# Make sed regex alternations follow left to right precedence?

Tags: regex, sed, xxd, alternation, regex-alternation

I'm trying to use a regex to format some binary from `xxd -b`, but to demonstrate this simply I'll show you what I expect to happen:

Regex to delete: `/1x|1.*/`

Text: `1x21y3333333313333` -> `2`

Where all occurrences of `1x` are deleted, then everything starting at the first 1 that shows up should be deleted. It should be immediately obvious what's going on, but if it's not, [play with this](https://regex101.com/r/oV2z54/1/debugger). The key is that if `1x` is matched, the rest of the pattern should be aborted.

Here is the output from `echo "AA" | xxd -b` (the bindump of `AA\n`):

```
0000000: 01000001 01000001 00001010                             AA.
```

My goal is to 1. delete the first 0 for every byte (ascii = 7 bits) and 2. delete the rest of the string so only the actual binary is kept. So I have piped it into `sed 's/ 0//g'`:

```
0000000:100000110000010001010                             AA.
```

Adding the second step, `sed -E 's/ 0| .*//g'`:

```
0000000:
```

Obviously, I expect to instead get:

```
0000000:100000110000010001010
```

Things I've tried but haven't done the job:

- `xxd` can take `-g0` to merge the columns, but it retains the first zero in every byte (characters each take up a byte, not 7 bits)
- `-r`

I will use perl instead in the meantime, but this behaviour baffles me and maybe there's a reason (lesson) here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this produces what you want:

```
$ echo "AA" | xxd -b | sed -E 's/ 0|  .*//g'
00000000:100000110000010001010
```

The key change here is the use of two blanks in front of `.*` so that this only matches the part that you want to remove.

Alternatively, we can remove blank-zero first:

```
$ echo "AA" | xxd -b | sed -E 's/ 0//g; s/ .*//'
00000000:100000110000010001010
```

Comment: I like the second snippet, it made me slap myself. Instead of doing the alternations in a regex, I could just split it!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 s/ 0| [^0].*//g
```

The reason of the seen behavior is that POSIX rules the engines to follow the **longest possible match** standard. So as long as the second side of alternation is longer than first, even being second in order, it matches earlier.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right. After looking up "posix longest match" and jumping through two links, apparently it says so [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html): "If the pattern permits a variable number of matching characters and thus there is more than one such sequence starting at that point, the longest such sequence is matched. [...] the ERE "(wee|week)(knights|night)" matches all ten characters of the string "weeknights"." Definitely counter-intuitive after having used a lot of modern regexes...

Comment: Although this answer fits the given input string, it will fail if a sequence starts e.g. with `1`. The right way is the second approach of John1024's.

Comment: @revo My update to https://stackoverflow.com/a/216228/6309 was not complete enough?

Comment: @VonC It was. I wanted to draw more attention to involve more people in. Unfortunately, I forgot to give the bounty at the end of period.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/\s+(0|[a-z.]+)//ig'
```