# Git SourceTree merge doesn't pull changes

Tags: git

I have a strange issue with `SourceTree`. I merged my feature branch with the `development` branch and it was ok. No problem.

Then I merged the `development` to the `main` branch. It says conflicts, but it doesn't show any conflicted files whatsoever. When I do continue the merging, it merged successfully, without any changes detected from my feature branch.

I realized it after a while because when I connect to the production DB (which I usually don't do), it shows a different schema than my local main branch. But when I tried to merge the development branch again, it doesn't pull the feature changes that I worked on. Anyone can explain this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting my local `main` branch and recreate it from the `development` branch. This answer doesn't explain what was happening so feel free to add more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the feature branch was already merge into `dev`, merging `dev` itself does not need/pull the feature branch (since it is already part of dev history).

But the best practice is to *not* merge integration branches (like dev or main).
Only merge feature branches (to dev first, then second merge of feature to main)

That way, you have:

- less conflicts
- only the feature branches you need in main (since not all of them are always eligible for `main`)

Comment: Nice tips on best practice  +1. But my decision to merge from feature -> development -> main is also a best practice tip I got from Git flow, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Seto My recommendation is based on [gitworkflow (one word)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216228/6309). I consider it a "better" best-practice in that it allows to be flexible and only merge what you actually need.

Comment: So this means that the development and main branch might be different, right? That sounds against the convention. Or maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Seto `dev` and `main` *are* different: not all feature branches integrated (merged) in `dev` are necessarily good candidates and/or ready for `main`.