# What is best practice for a long running Git branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I've been reading the excellent [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) to gain an *understanding* of git actions, however there is one scenario illustrated which I cannot understand from what the book is saying.

In the section on [Basic Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), under the heading **Basic Merging**, the following example is given.

The before state is this:

```
                      * master
C0 --- C1 --- C2 --- C4
                \
                 --- C3 --- C5
                             * iss53
```

A merge is then performed of `iss53` into `master` resulting in this.

```
                                 * master
C0 --- C1 --- C2 --- C4 ------- C6
                \             /
                 --- C3 --- C5
                             * iss53
```

This is a good result for the `master` branch as it now includes the work done on the `iss53` branch. Or, in other words, `master` contains 'everything'.

However, there is talk in various parts of the book about "long running" branches. If `iss53` were intended to be such a branch, I see a problem in that further change on that branch does *not* include anything from the `master` branch after `C2` and so further work is (theoretically) necessitated on future merges.

From reading other questions, the apparent answer is to subsequently merge in the other direction, which would fast-forward `iss53` to `C6` from where it can once again diverge.

Furthermore, if `C4` had not existed at the time of the original merge, it would (by default) have simply fast-forwarded `master` to `C5` which negates the need for the reverse merge.

So these situations have me questioning whether to accept fast-forward merges as a time saving and always reverse-merge non-fast-forwards, or whether there is value in mandating `--no-ff` and the reverse merge simply for consistency.

Are there reasons *not* to do the reverse merge, and consequently, perhaps, to always use `--no-ff`?

As I stated at the beginning, I am just trying to *understand* git at this stage. I do not have a specific scenario I am working with. I'm still formulating an approach.

Comment: Many are of the opinion that once the `iss53` branch has been merged into `master`, it should be retired and not used anymore.  If you do want to use `iss53` as a long running branch _and_ keep it updated with `master`, then yes you will need to do a reverse merge.

Comment: Fast-forwarding removes the information on when the merge happened and how much was merged at a time (other than in the committer timestamp), which you may or may not care about.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there reasons not to do the reverse merge

Usually you do not merge integration branches (like `dev` or `main` or `master`) to other branches.

Integration branches are branches you are merging *to*, not from.

If `iss53` itself is a long-lived branch, once you have merged it to `main`/`master`, you would recreate `iss53` on top of `main`/`master`, to create additional commits.
But the usual best practice is to create short-lived feature branches, each one dedicated to a specific feature, that you would merge to dev (first-level integration), then merge that *same feature branch* to `main`/`master` if you think it is ready to be integrated and deployed to production.

That is called **[gitworkflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216228/6309)** (one word).

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting approach.