# How to merge release branch to main in case of conflicts

Tags: bitbucket, git-merge, branching-and-merging, release-management

I have a release branch.
After releasing the version, I am creating a tag and merging the branch into develop.
In some cases there are merge conflicts.
What is the best way to resolve conflicts, should I resolve them while merging onto the tip of main branch?
what is the best practice.

P.s we are using bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

A release branch is an integration branch (A branch where you integrate multiple feature branches in order to build your release, [gitworkflow-style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216228/6309))

The best practice is to *not* merge integration branches (like `dev` or `main` or `master`) to other branches.

Integration branches are branches you are merging to, not from.

Ideally, you would reset/recreate develop on top of the new release, and go on from there.
Or you would rebase develop on top of that release tag.