# How should I implement versioning within mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tags, branch, versioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use mercurial for release management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827628/how-to-use-mercurial-for-release-management)

What should I use for versioning my applications using mercurial? Should I use tags, branching, any other option? Right now I'm branching for every deployed version of my application with a name specifying which version it is. Am I doing it wrong? Is there a better solution?

Here's a history view of my repository:

[image]

Comment: There's already a dozen question here concerning which is the best way to manage release with Mercurial, for example : [How to use mercurial for release management?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827628/how-to-use-mercurial-for-release-management)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Mercurial, but had plenty of experience with Perforce and can tell you what we did.

We would Label or Tag each build that was a release, but only branch if we needed to change it.  This way you only add the additional overhead of a branch when you actually need to branch your code.

Comment: I wonder if your solution would be the same in Mercurial as it's implementation is different than other source controls

Comment: The idea I think is the same as you can create a branch from a historical point.

Answer (score 1):

You can already find a lot of various question about this exact topic. For example :

- [How to use mercurial for release management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827628/how-to-use-mercurial-for-release-management)
- [Mercurial: Named Branches vs Multiple Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890723/mercurial-named-branches-vs-multiple-repositories)
- [How do you maintain development code and production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216212/how-do-you-maintain-development-code-and-production-code)
- [What are some good strategies to allow deployed applications to be hotfixable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143814/what-are-some-good-strategies-to-allow-deployed-applications-to-be-hotfixable)

Hopefully you will find all the answers you need their ! You can also follow the various links provided in the "Related" secion on the right.